# PHP - Create unlimited depth array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sitemap

I have to build sitemap.html generator, that creates a tree of URLs.

So for instance if I have those URLs:

https://some.url/with/something/good/ and https://some.url/with/something/bad/

it will create something like this:

```
- https://some.url/
   - https://some.url/with/
      - https://some.url/with/something/
          - https://some.url/with/something/good/
          - https://some.url/with/something/bad/
```

I have array of every URL from my site, now I was thinking of building multidimensional array.

Example above would be converted to something like this:

```
$url_structure['https://some.url/']['https://some.url/with/']['https://some.url/with/something/']['https://some.url/with/something/good/'] = 0;
```

Which will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [https://some.url/] => Array
        (
            [https://some.url/with/] => Array
                (
                    [https://some.url/with/something/] => Array
                        (
                            [https://some.url/with/something/good/] => 0
                            [https://some.url/with/something/bad/] => 0
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Have you got an idea how to do that better? That's the only solution I have in mind so far.

Problem is I can't find the way to create something like this, because I don't really know how depth this array will become. I just have array of URLs (around 20k URLs).

Output to sitemap.html is a list that I did above.

Comment: You could remove the parent URL in the child-element.

Comment: you have 20k URLs in your site?   I would simplify your sitemap and forget being so granular.

Comment: I will remove parent, that is just for you to better understand. Sitemap needs to contain all the URLs, that's my requirement from SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reference variable to do the job in such way

```
$list = [
'https://some.url/with/something/good/',
'https://some.url/with/something/bad/',
];

$res = [];
foreach ($list as $x) {
    // remove root. you can add it after loop.
    $x = substr($x, strlen('https://some.url/'));
    $path = preg_split('~/+~', trim($x, '/'));
    // point to the array
    $p = &$res;
    foreach($path as $step) {
        if(! isset($p[$step])) {
            //  add next level if it's absent
            $p[$step] = [];
        }
        // go to next level
        $p = &$p[$step];
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8647cf73e7cb74279b945177d6ce99cd89d5e49)

Comment: That's it! Thank you!